# php regex to extract specific domain with/without www http https from href

Tags: php, regex

im trying to check for the a tags which contains specific domain ... but this a tag  might be with or without `www` , `hhtp` , `https`

```
$a = '  <a href="https://example.com"></a>
                <a href="http://www.example.com"></a> 
                <a href="http://example.com"></a> 
                <a href="https://www.example.com"></a> 
                <a href="http://example.com"></a> 
                ';
        $reg_exUrl = "/(http|https)\:\/\/(www.)?example+\.com(\/\S*)?/";

        preg_match($reg_exUrl, $a, $url) ;
        var_dump($url);
```

but i dont get all the links this is the output

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => "https://example.com"
  1 => "https"
]
```

also im not sure how to include `href` so it would only search inside href

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have:

```
$a = '  <a href="https://example.com"></a>
            <a href="http://www.example.com"></a> 
            <a href="http://example.com"></a> 
            <a href="https://www.example.com"></a> 
            <a href="http://example.com"></a> 
            ';
    $reg_exUrl = "/href=\"(?:https?)\:\/\/(?:www\.)?example\.com\"/";

    preg_match_all($reg_exUrl, $a, $url) ;
    var_dump($url);
```

Comment: thanx , how you add `href` in there ? so it would only search inside href not the whole string

Comment: I've updated the answer. The only thing is to escape quotes `"` >> `\"`

Answer (score 3):

Use a HTML parser, and then the URL parser to get the domain. From there use a regex on the limited string:

```
$a = '  <a href="https://example.com"></a>
                <a href="http://www.example.com"></a> 
                <a href="http://example.com"></a> 
                <a href="https://www.example.com"></a> 
                <a href="http://example.com"></a> 
                ';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($a);
$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach($links as $link) {
    $host = parse_url($link->getAttribute('href'))['host'];
    if(!empty($host) && preg_match('/(^|\.)example\.com$/', $host)) {
         echo 'Expected domain';
    } 
}
```

Also to explain a bit more about what your current output was...`preg_match` outputs the first match found and each index is one capture group.

```
 $reg_exUrl = "/(http|https)\:\/\/(www.)?example+\.com(\/\S*)?/";
                 ^^^^^^^^^^        ^^^^                ^^^^^
```

So as displayed above you have 3 possible capture groups. You can use `?:` at the start of them so it is not captured. You `http|https` can be simplified to `https?` (the `?` makes the `s` optional.

Comment: thanx , i knew about that but this might give me `otherexample.com/script.php?link=example.com` or something like that which is not what i want

Comment: @hretic Actually `(^|\.)` is what you'd want. See https://3v4l.org/Ihs6s I think that is all edge cases.

Comment: Good answer. You can also move all the test part into a function and use an XPath query, see https://3v4l.org/4WZPi

Answer (score -1):

instead of `preg_match`, use `preg_match_all`

***UPD***: all url site regex:

```
$regex = '/href="(.*?)"/';
```

Comment: This will match more than `example.com`.